# getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() and MotionEvent.getY() returns differnt values?

Tags: events

I'm having issues with how my screen works. I can get the height of the screen by:

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); // == 800
```

When I press the screen, I get a specific value:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
........
........
      (int) (event.getY(pointerIndex)); // == 701
```

The problem I'm having is the most I can get on the Y axis is 700!!!

Any suggestions whats going on?

If you need more information please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was digging around there for quite a bit but I've found the solution. Thank this thread:

Motionevent.getX and getY

Basically, the touch screen is completely independent from the pixels on your screen. So for example, above the height I was getting was actually the pixels

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(); // == 800
```

I got the actual height of the touch screen from the view

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
v.getHeight() // == 724
v.getWidth() // == 480
```

Hope that helps any poor lost souls!!

Answer (score 0):

I know the solution of the problem. It is caused by the header and the title bar. They are counted in the event of the display.getHeight(). You may remove them this is absolutely up to you.